# Django view testing: Should status code be tested separately from template used?

Tags: python, django

I've created a test for one of my views. The function:

1. Asserts if the status code is 200
2. Asserts if the template was used

Best practice wise, should these tests be kept separate? I'm concerned that I'm violating SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) by giving this function multiple assertions.

The code works as is, this is merely an opinion question (sorry if this question should be somewhere else).

```
def test_contacts_GET(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.contacts_url)
        request = self.client.get(self.contacts_url)
        self.assertEqual(request.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'crm/contacts.html')
```

All tests are passing as is. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert as many tests as you want as long as you only test a single thing in SRP. In your question you called `get` twice, which violates SRP. You can modify your code like this:

```py
def test_contacts_GET(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.contacts_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'crm/contacts.html')
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the double get statement is what prompted me to ask this question. Can I ask what the semantic difference is between request and response? I'm assuming that's django speak.

Comment: ```response``` is what you get back from the view you are testing. As you are testing a ```get``` request you do not need a ```request``` in your case. Actually you might need ```request``` when you are testing a POST view.